# RegEx to invalid a string if it contains a certain word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am making a validation for my invoiceId which basically allows all letters and numbers and the dash character (-), and it doesn't allow the word draft in any part of the string, for example:

**Valid cases:**

- 123456
- InvoiceId-1234
- -1234-Invoice-Id

**Invalid cases:**

- draft-234
- invoicedraft123
- 12345draft
- -draft

This is the regex I am using to validate alphanumeric characters and special characters:

**[a-zA-Z0-9-]+**

I have tried the negative look ahead for here are my attempts:

**/^\b(?:(?!(D|d)(R|r)(A|a)(F|f)(T|t))[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;**

This one just stops the word draft at the beginning

and
**/^((?!draft).)*([a-zA-Z0-9-])$;**

This one allows special characters.

Is it posible to have create a regex with my requirements?

Comment: Do it with two regexs.

Comment: Use negative lookahead: `/^(?!.*draft)[a-z0-9-]+$/i`

Comment: Exactly like above. If whole word `draft` is meant, enclose with `\b`s: `/^(?!.*\bdraft\b)[a-z0-9-]+$/i`

Comment: @anubhava this works, thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I enclose it with b it deosn;t work, thank you.

Comment: It just depends on the requirements.